# Clicks or ticks every minute when HDD is idle

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, external-drive, portable-harddrive

My HDD is a Western Digital (WD) My Passport... It's 2 weeks old. I hear this tick or click followed by another one about 8-9 secs later, and they repeat every minute almost exactly... They usually happen and the LED light blinking..

It's not like the other clicks you hear that indicate any inevitable HDD failure; it's much lower in volume. I don't know what this is, however it's different than the rest of the HDD usual sounds...It's close to the sound of a mouse click.

It sometimes also happens when I access a file on the drive mostly after being idle for a while, sometimes randomly not really sure...

The drive though is working well, the SMART report comes out OK and without warning, and disk management shows it healthy... What could be the cause of this??

Answer (score 1):

Most likely what you're hearing are the heads parking.  I'm assuming it's a 2.5" drive, they're designed to be bumped around more often than 3.5" drives so the firmware is designed to park the heads after a period of inactivity to prevent damage should the drive get bumped while it's spinning.  I wouldn't worry about it, I've had multiple laptops that have done that and the drives are still going strong.

Some people will tell you that the constant parking/unparking increases the duty cycles on the drive, I've read stats where the average drive failure is after so many million duty cycles.  Most drives will never reach that point under normal usage.  But if you're concerned about it there are some commands you can execute in certain OSes (only done this in Linux) to control the different power save and protection features.

https://xenomorph.net/misc/clicking-hard-drives/

I haven't tried all the commands and tools on there, but it seemed to be the site with the most comprehensive info on the subject that I could find.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That was very helpful.. So why do you think the hard drive needs to park the heads every minute? Since they were parked once shouldn't it be enough, until I reuse it? Would the clicks I hear other times, other than the constant every minute click be explained that the heads are unparking, according to an action by my side? And finally from your experience wouldn't it be wise  to leave it that way safe from bumps, or it's just useless and headache?